# How would I redirect console output for all applications a application I launch using a Process

Tags: c#, process

I'm redirecting a application which spawns a conhost.exe. How would I attach to that and redirect the output/input?

Answer (score -1):

> How would I attach to that and redirect the output/input?

Use the [Process Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.diagnostics.process%28v=vs.100%29.aspx). With it you can set the arguments to run the process as well as redirect the standard input, output and error.

Here's an [article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/190351) on using the windows api directly.

Comment: The problem is, This application is spawning it's own shell even though I'm redirecting it. I need to redirect all child processes it spawns as well.

Comment: Added more info for you.

Comment: Sorry, but I'm not seeing anything that addresses the issue of redirection of output for a child conhost.exe process.